# How do I find the common factor from a stochastic process ARMA model

Tags: time-series, arima, stochastic-processes, moving-average

How would you factorise this ?
There should be a common factor between the Lag polynomial of the auto regressing moving average A(L) and the for the lag polynomial moving average B(L).

It should be simplified to a ARMA(1,1) model, without the c, which is a constant.

$$∆y_t = (0.3 + c)y_{t−1} − 0.3cy_{t−2} + ε_t + (0.5 − c)ε_{t−1} − 0.5cε_{t−2}`$$

Comment: You present a single equation but refer to "them:" what do you mean by that??

Comment: Sorry, my bad, will put more detail